# Unsure how to break down this assignment task

Tags: algorithm

A particular Unix kernel operation handles disk I/O by allowing independent user
processes to place I/O request blocks (IORB) in a linked list. The order in which these
requests are serviced depends on their scheduling priority. The scheduling strategy is
adaptive, which simply means that the kernel may carry out different computations at
different times in order to calculate the priority value for each element of the list.
You are required to design, implement and test a C function sort list()on Unix/Linux,
which will sort such a list either in ascending or descending order according to the preference
order computed by whatever function is passed as its second argument. The first
argument is to be a pointer to the head of the list. Since the kernel has other structures
with pointers to IORB blocks, the list must be sorted in place.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately SO is no tutoring service. Questions are required to be specific and clear. Reading the tags of your question you seem to have not yet understood what really is key in the assignemnt. It is not about I/O, kernel, system programming or unix. It is simply about writing a sort function that sorts a linked list. Please try to focus on that part and refine your question accordingly. Also you need to show us your current effort and where **exactly** you are stuck with it.

Comment: @Gerhardh Seems like a reasonable algorithm question to me. I've fixed the tags accordingly.

Comment: @user3386109 If the op had removed the homework-assignement-candy about Unix I/O and formulated a question how to implement a sorting function, then I would fully agree with you. Besides that the language tag might be relevant.

Comment: @Gerhardh thats where I was stuck I didn't really read it properly and just needed an extra set of eyes that knows alot more about programming than me to help me figure out the actual question. I know I am new but I will be more careful next time, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be begging for a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). Go through the entire list to find the smallest element (according to the comparison function). Take that element out of the list, and add it at the end of the list. Then repeat the process, each time finding the smallest element of the remaining list, and putting it at the end.

For example, if you have a list of 10 elements, then find the smallest of the 10, and move it to the end. Then find the smallest of the first 9 elements, and move it to the end. Repeat until there's only 1 element, which gets moved to the end.